# How can I use Floating UI as a Chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, floating-ui

The goal is to insert tooltips into specific elements on web pages using the Chrome extension.

I tried using the [ESM version](https://floating-ui.com/docs/getting-started) of Floating UI as a content script but getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
> import{computePosition as t,rectToClientRect as e}from"/npm/@floating-ui/core@1.3.1/+esm";

The manifest looks smth like that:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "floating-esm.js",
        "content.js"
      ],
      "type": "module",
      "css": [
        "tooltips.css"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Was expecting to have access to computePosition function in the main content script file.

Comment: Don't use esm version, use a standard one. You can't specify `type` in content_scripts, ChatGPT has lied to you.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't seem to do anything.

By the standard you mean UMD? I tried but couldn't get the functions to work.

Comment: I guess you didn't use it correctly. From what I see in the documentation you'd need two files (core and dom), then your content.js will use FloatingUICore FloatingUIDOM globals directly.

Comment: Can't believe I missed it. Thank you! Got it working. Will update the thread with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially imported Core and Dom and changed the update() function a bit like to include **window.FloatingUIDOM** and **window.FloatingUICore**:

```
    window.FloatingUIDOM.computePosition(markedDiv, tooltip, {
  placement: "top",
  middleware: [
    window.FloatingUICore.offset(6),
    window.FloatingUIDOM.flip(),
    window.FloatingUIDOM.shift({ padding: 5 }),
    window.FloatingUIDOM.arrow({ element: arrowElement }),
  ],
})
```

I think in their original sample code the markedDiv was called "button" but it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).